# apache - RewriteEngine doesn't work outside <VirtualHost> Directive

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, virtual-hosts

I'm trying to configure apache to redirect the requests containing only hostname (domain) to another path.
I found the following directives useful, but as long as those are enclosed in `VirtualHost`, put in `site_available` folder (`/etc/apache2/`) and enabled as a separate site (with `a2ensite` command).

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myserver:80

    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/path/to/myproject/myproject.wsgi

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /path/path [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Note that only `Rewrite*` directives don't work. The alias to my Python project works fine.

Morover, I found out that if I disable other virtual host(s) (000-default) with `a2dissite` command and put the directives mentioned above (without `VirtualHost`) to httpd.conf file everything (including the `Rewrite*` rules) work.

So, I am in doubt why I couldn't get this done in simple server config context, and what is the solution?

Comment: Are you trying to say that your rewrites don't work when moved to an .htaccess file? I'm slightly confused. Did you make sure to put the RewriteEngine On at the beginning of the rules?

Comment: @Anirudh, yes, I'm talking about rewrites. I'm not sure about the relation between .htaccess file and httpd.conf, but my case is with httpd.conf. So the rewrites don't work when they are in httpd.conf. `RewriteEngine On` is included too.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it appears that the `Rewrite*` directives do not work in the server configuration and need to be declared inside the `VirtualHost` is because (from the [`RewriteEngine`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteengine) documentation):

> [...] rewrite configurations are not inherited by virtual hosts. This means that you need to have a `RewriteEngine on` directive for each virtual host in which you wish to use rewrite rules.

To change this behaviour, you can set [`RewriteOptions`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteoptions) to something `InheritDownBefore` or similar. You then still need to have a `RewriteEngine On` on each `VirtualHost` but at least you won't need to copy the rewrite rules on each one.

So, taking your code example, this should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions InheritDownBefore
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /path/path [R=301,L]

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myserver:80
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/path/to/myproject/myproject.wsgi
    RewriteEngine On
</VirtualHost>
```